# Does std::thread::join throw std::invalid_argument when it is not joinable?

Tags: c++11

Based on STL documentation, [std::thread::join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) throws std::invalid_argument when it is not joinable, it is not easy for me to understand its design rationale.

Questions:

1. There is no input arguments for std::thread::join, what is the purpose to throw std::invalid_argument exception?
2. Isn't it better to call std::terminate instead for std::thread::join when it is not joinable instead?

Comment: `std::terminate` does exactly what it sounds like: It terminates the program unconditionally. At least an exception is possible to catch.

Answer (score 1):

> Does std::thread::join throw std::invalid_argument when it is not joinable?

Yes.

> There is no input arguments for std::thread::join, what is the purpose to throw std::invalid_argument exception?

There is one implicit argument if you will: `*this`

> Isn't it better to call std::terminate instead for std::thread::join when it is not joinable instead?

If you don't catch the exception, `std::terminate` *will* get called.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WT5r8Yx9P)

Comment: thanks for clarification, I understand it now.